# Why histogram from `ggplot()` is same as for only for one variable used for `aes` `fill`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, histogram, fill

The question is about two observations related to following 3 figures:

> (1) Why the histograms in (a) and (b) are different if number of bins is same? 
>   (2) Histogram in (b) is exactly same as the histogram for the fill `nonsmo`. If this is the case then how to make histogram of complete data using ggplot()?

(a) Plot using `hist(chol$AGE,30)`.

[image: Histogram using hist()]

(b) Histogram plotted with `ggplot(data=chol, aes(chol$AGE)) + geom_histogram()` and default values i.e. 30 bins.

[image: Histogram with ggplot()]

(c) Now adding fill with respect to the variable `SMOKE`:

```
ggplot(data=chol, aes(chol$AGE)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = chol$SMOKE))
```

[image: Histogram using ggplot() with fill.]

Comment: When you use `ggplot(data=chol, ...)`, you should never use `chol$` in your aesthetics or anywhere else in any of the ggplot verbs (unless you are providing a different subset on the data, either `data=` or `subset=`. It is never needed, often problematic. It should be just `ggplot(data, aes(AGE)) + ...`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @r2evans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there are a large number of values matching the bins upper and lower limits so depending on the preferences, of whether it is left-open or right-open there could be a significant shift in bins.

For example compare:

```
set.seed(10)
age<-as.integer(rnorm(100, 50, 20))
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
hist(age, 30, right=TRUE)
hist(age, 30, right=FALSE)
```

[image]
Notice, only about 18 bins were created (bin width of 5)

With ggplot2, where the bins are shifted to the center of the bin range:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(age), aes(age)) +geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did after comments by @Dave2e

```
ggplot(data=chol, aes(AGE, fill = SMOKE)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), binwidth = 1, position = "stack")

hist(chol$AGE, breaks = 30, right = FALSE)
```

[image]

[image]

Adding correct value for `binwidth`, realizing by default `position` is `stack` and using `right` as `false` got exactly same histograms.